# In-App Purchase status

Tags: in-app-purchase

I have a question. I had some in-app purchase products, all consumable. The Apple rejected the app, because some of that products should be non-renewing subscription products. So I created a new products as non-renewing subscription and status of that products is "Ready to Submit", so everything is ok, but 3 of my products must be consumable and when the Apple rejected the status of that products was "Developer Need Action", but when I changed some languages and price, the status changed to "Waiting for Review". Now when I want to upload a new binary I can only select the subscriptions products, there are not on the list my consumable products. When I select only subscription products and upload binary will Apple check also my consumable products and will they be available when Apple acceppt the app?

Greets